# Creating an indoor map from images

Tags: leaflet, geojson, indoor-positioning-system

I have floor plans saved as JPEG's that I need to create maps of. I need to be able to host these as maps using a map API(have messed with leaflet and indoor.js). These are private locations so just dropping them into Google Maps doesn't really seem to be an option. Is there a good way to do this?